# Best practice of css in Mui and Reactjs

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, material-ui

I'm new to mui , i'm doing CSS in mui components like this

```
<Typography
    variant="h5"
    sx={{
      fontWeight: "bold",
      color: "#1a759f",
      display: "flex",
      justifyContent: "center",
      margin: "20vh",
    }}
   >
   Topology
</Typography>
```

but this is inline CSS which is not a good practice , tell me an alternative to that

Comment: Why isn't it a good practice?

Comment: as inline css will cause speed problems in future

Comment: Inline css alone doesn’t cause performance issues, that’s incorrect.

Comment: “Best practices” is a dangerous phrase. Searching for them causes you to blindly follow (and advise) patterns without understanding why.

Comment: okayy got it !!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move to a variable

```
const styles = {

  typographyStyle: {
        fontWeight: "bold",
        color: "#1a759f",
        display: "flex",
        justifyContent: "center",
        margin: "20vh",
  },
};
```

in the element

```
  sx={[styles.typographyStyle]}
```